# Filtering out values from an enum to ComboBox binding using a MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, enums

I'm using the `MarkupExtension` outlined in this answer for binding my `enum`s to `ComboBox`s:
[Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf#answer-4398752)

Which is convenient because it allows me to do something like this:

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{util:Enumeration {x:Type viewModels:MyEnumTypeE}}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding MyEnumValue, FallbackValue=0}"   
    SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

which is what I'm used to seeing when I bind my `ComboBox`s to most anything else.

I'm having trouble, however, because now I need to filter out certain enumeration values. I also need to selectively filter them out at run-time, so that sometimes all of my `enum` values are displayed, and sometimes only a few of the values are displayed.

This question, [Binding WPF ComboBox to enum and hiding certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997898/binding-wpf-combobox-to-enum-and-hiding-certain-values#answer-20998037), seemed like the perfect title to answer the question, but they are using the `ObjectDataProvider` which I am not. I suppose I could always default back to using that if I really needed to, but since the `MarkupExtension` is just so darn convenient, I would like to continue using that instead.

My question is: how could I filter out some `enum` values from my `ComboBox` while still using this `MarkupExtension`?

Comment: Can't you use another attribute ( for instance `Browsable`) for filtering?

Comment: Honestly, I know very little about attributes. I may have to play around with them a bit. Do you know if I can toggle it on/off during run-time? Sometimes my entire enum needs displayed; sometimes only part of it.

Comment: That's the point - no. Attributes can only be used for static behavior. If you need dynamic filtering, you need something else. Which I don't know what could be.